# Faces that were invisible on Blender become visible in powerpoint

Tags: 3d-view

I've created a project and it looks like this : [image]

But once I export it through FBX, STL or other formats to powerpoint it looks like this: [image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem and make the cube mesh invisible on powerpoint too?

Comment: How have you made it invisible in Blender? Does this apply? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures). Also note that you can't export unapplied modifiers such as Boolean modifiers from Blender.

Comment: Yes it looks like you need to apply a boolean or delete the boolean object

Comment: Of course it looks like this, because FBX, STL and other formats do not have Blender's _Boolean_ modifier. To them those are all just objects. As mentioned by moonboots, You have to apply the modifier (and either delete the cube before export or check the option to only export selected objects and of course not have the cube selected).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now.